# Sequence contains no elements - LINQ, MVC, Average

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, linq, entity-framework

I am running into this error. I see that the reason is because the average returned at times is 0.00 which from a data stand point is accurate. This SQL query works fine, but that is because it puts in 0.00 automatically.

LINQ complains and so I tried using `DefaultIfEmpty()` but it says it is expecting my ViewModel.

```
Dim ticketCounts = From t In queue _
   Where _
    (t.StatusId = 2) And _
    (t.CloseDate.Year = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now).Year) And _
    (t.ResolutionDays > 0)
   Group t By _
    Column1 = CType(t.CloseDate.Month, Integer), _
    Column2 = CType(t.CloseDate.ToString("MMMM"), String) _
    Into g = Group _
   Order By Column1 _
   Select _
    Id = Column1, _
    Month = Column2, _
    Critical = g.Where(Function(t) t.PriorityId = 1).DefaultIfEmpty().Average(Function(t) t.ResolutionDays), _
    High = g.Where(Function(t) t.PriorityId = 2).DefaultIfEmpty().Average(Function(t) t.ResolutionDays), _
    Normal = g.Where(Function(t) t.PriorityId = 3).DefaultIfEmpty().Average(Function(t) t.ResolutionDays), _
    Low = g.Where(Function(t) t.PriorityId = 4).DefaultIfEmpty().Average(Function(t) t.ResolutionDays), _
    Total = g.Where(Function(t) t.Id <> Nothing).DefaultIfEmpty().Average(Function(t) t.ResolutionDays)
```

**UPDATED!**
This is the SQL query doing the same thing I need VB to do.

```
SELECT
    DATENAME(MONTH,t.CloseDate) AS 'Month',
    AVG(CASE WHEN (t.PriorityId = 1) THEN CAST(t.ResolutionDays AS Decimal(18, 2)) ELSE 0 END) AS 'Critical',
    AVG(CASE WHEN (t.PriorityId = 2) THEN CAST(t.ResolutionDays AS Decimal(18, 2)) ELSE 0 END) AS 'High',
    AVG(CASE WHEN (t.PriorityId = 3) THEN CAST(t.ResolutionDays AS Decimal(18, 2)) ELSE 0 END) AS 'Normal',
    AVG(CASE WHEN (t.PriorityId = 4) THEN CAST(t.ResolutionDays AS Decimal(18, 2)) ELSE 0 END) AS 'Low',
    AVG(CAST(t.ResolutionDays AS Decimal(18, 2))) AS 'Monthly Average'
FROM
    tblMaintenanceTicket t
WHERE
    t.StatusId = 2
    AND YEAR(t.CloseDate) = year(getdate())
GROUP BY 
    MONTH(t.CloseDate),
    DATENAME(MONTH,t.CloseDate)
ORDER BY
    MONTH(t.CloseDate)
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The problem is that all of the scalar LINQ methods (Average, Max, etc ...) throw an exception if the input `IEnumerable(Of T)` doesn't have any elements.  It looks like the `g.Where` calls are resulting in an empty collection resulting in the exception.

What you may want to do is write a method which handles the empty case and returns a default value.

Comment: I have tried that suggestion a couple different ways, but can this type of thing be complete inline? Like an inline conditional? I clearly know very little about LINQ lol.

Comment: @Chuck why can't you use defaultifempty? It is meant for this kind of stuff

Comment: I was not exacly sure where to put it. If I put it right after the where clause like g.Where(Function(t) t.PriorityId = 4).DefaultIfEmpty() that it cannot convert to my ViewModelType.

Comment: @Chuck you have to put it just before your `Average` call.

Comment: Unfortunately that creates an "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." error on the Average call t.ResolutionDays.

Comment: @Chuck you should really show that code where you are calling DefaultIfEmpty

Comment: I have updated my above example with the DefaultIfEmpty() code.

Comment: @JaredPar, I think you shouldn't say `Sum` there. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338442.aspx. *This method returns zero if source contains no elements.*

Answer (score 33):

The default value is `null` for `o`bject. Therefore `DefaultIfEmpty().Average(x => x.Value)` will throw the exception.

Instead, use:

```
Critical = 
    g.Where(Function(t) t.PriorityId = 1)
    .Select(Function(t) t.ResolutionDays)
    .DefaultIfEmpty().Average()
```

Reference:
http://geekswithblogs.net/SoftwareDoneRight/archive/2011/02/15/fixing-linq-error-sequence-contains-no-elements.aspx

Comment: DefaultIfEmpty().Average(x => x?.Value) to return null or DefaultIfEmpty().Average(x => x?.Value ?? default(<datatype>)) to return datatype-default

Comment: ".DefaultIfEmpty()" is the key! Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

This is the helper method I have used.

```
    public static double AverageOrDefault(this IEnumerable<double> enumerable)
    {
        return enumerable.DefaultIfEmpty().Average();
    }

    public static double AverageOrDefault<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, Func<T, double> selector)
    {
        return enumerable.Select(selector).DefaultIfEmpty().Average();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar solution just adding up a bit:)
Check this...

```
Critical = g.Where(t => t.PriorityId == 1).Select(t => (decimal) t.ResolutionDays).DefaultIfEmpty().Average()
```

Note: if your value is integer don't forget to cast it to decimal by adding (decimal) before the value.